# SAP HANA random number generator

Tags: sql, hana

I want to write a statement that generates a random pick from a set of four values (2,4,6, and 8). Below is the select statement that I have so far

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN RN_GENERATOR.RANDOM_NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND 2.00 THEN 2 
WHEN RN_GENERATOR.RANDOM_NUMBER BETWEEN 2.01 AND 4.00 THEN 4
WHEN RN_GENERATOR.RANDOM_NUMBER BETWEEN 4.01 AND 6.00 THEN 6
WHEN RN_GENERATOR.RANDOM_NUMBER BETWEEN 6.01 AND 8.00 THEN 8
END     AS ORDER_FREQUENCY
FROM (SELECT ROUND(RAND()*8,2) AS RANDOM_NUMBER FROM DUMMY) RN_GENERATOR
```

is there a more intelligent way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me as if your requirement can be fulfilled but his statement

```
select
        ROUND(rand()*4, 0, ROUND_CEILING) * 2 as ORDER_FREQUENCY
from dummy;
```

`RAND() * 4` spreads the value range of possible outcomes for the `RAND()` function from 0..1 to 0..4.

`ROUND( ... , 0, ROUND_CEILING)` rounds the number to the next larger or equal integer and leaves no decimal places. For this example this means that the output of this rounding can only be 1, 2, 3 or 4.

`*2` simply maps the four possible values to your target number range 2, 4, 6, 8. If the multiplication wouldn't suffice, you could also use the `MAP()` function for this.

And that's it. Random numbers picked from the set of `(2, 4, 6, 8)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can randomly sort a data set by using

ORDER BY Rand()

and select first one as your random value

Here is an example

```
select top 1 rownum 
from Numbers_Table(10) as nt 
where rownum in (2,4,6,8)
order by rand();
```

Numbers_Table function returns a [numbers table on HANA database](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/create-numbers-table-function-on-sap-hana-database.aspx) and I filter only the values that you want to see as your possible random values using WHERE clause

TOP 1 clause in SELECT command returns the first integer which is randomly ordered

I hope it helps